# How to prepend int to slice

Tags: arrays, go, slice, prepend

I have a slice which I created using

```
var x []int;
for i := 2; i < 10; i += 2 {
    x = append(x, i);
}
```

I want to prepend an integer to this slice, something like

```
x = append(2, x)
```

but obviously it won't work since append needs a slice as the first argument.

I have tried [this](https://codingair.wordpress.com/2014/07/18/go-appendprepend-item-into-slice/) but it only works for strings and it's not working in my case.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Use a slice [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals): `[]int{1}`, For example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var x []int
    for i := 2; i < 10; i += 2 {
        x = append(x, i)
    }
    fmt.Println(x)

    x = append([]int{1}, x...)

    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Yc87gO7gJlD

Output:

```
[2 4 6 8]
[1 2 4 6 8]
```

---

However, this more efficient version may make fewer allocations, An allocation is only necessary when there is no spare slice capacity.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var x []int
    for i := 2; i < 10; i += 2 {
        x = append(x, i)
    }
    fmt.Println(x)

    x = append(x, 0)
    copy(x[1:], x)
    x[0] = 1

    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/fswXul_YfvD

Output:

```
[2 4 6 8]
[1 2 4 6 8]
```

---

Good code must be readable. In Go, we often hide implementaion details inside a function. Go compilers are optimizing compilers, small, simple functions (like `prependInt`) are inlined.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func prependInt(x []int, y int) []int {
    x = append(x, 0)
    copy(x[1:], x)
    x[0] = y
    return x
}

func main() {
    var x []int
    for i := 2; i < 10; i += 2 {
        x = append(x, i)
    }
    fmt.Println(len(x), cap(x), x)

    x = prependInt(x, 1)

    fmt.Println(len(x), cap(x), x)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/wl6gvoXraKH

Output:

```
4 4 [2 4 6 8]
5 8 [1 2 4 6 8]
```

---

See [Go SliceTricks](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks).

Comment: Any type of slice can be prepended using this. You have to use zero value for the first `append()` of the `prependInt` function. Eg for string - `append(x, "")`. Zero values for various types can are briefly described [here](https://go.dev/tour/basics/12)

Comment: These tricks are good if you only need to prepend an item or two. But if you're prepending in a loop, it is significantly better to reverse the array, **append** what you need, and then reverse the array again

Answer (score 10):

The current version is go1.14.11

Prepend without a for loop:

```
package main

import "fmt"
func main () {
  data := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
  fmt.Println(data)
  data = append([]int{99}, data...)
  fmt.Println(data)
}
```

Example taken form: https://codingair.wordpress.com/2014/07/18/go-appendprepend-item-into-slice/

Works with integers: https://play.golang.org/p/gaLhB5_d1Iu

Comment: does this allocate ? or is there some trick in the compiler to improve it ?

Comment: The prepend operation shown here is identical to the accepted answer.  The difference between this answer and the accepted answer is that the example data is created with a composite literal instead of a for loop.

Comment: @mh-cbon Yes, this allocates.  See `prependInt` in PeterSo's answer for a solution that minimizes allocations.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty late to the party but I haven't seen a generic version, so here is mine:

```
func Prepend[T any](slice []T, elems ...T) []T {
    return append(elems, slice...)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Another answer uses `append` and `copy`, but you can do it with just `append`,
in one or two lines:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
   {
      a := []int{20, 30}
      a = append(append(a, 10), a...)[len(a):]
      fmt.Println(a)
   }
   {
      a := []int{20, 30}
      a = append(make([]int, 1), a...)
      a[0] = 10
      fmt.Println(a)
   }
   { // if starting with empty slice, use: a := make([]int, 0, 1)
      a := []int{20, 30}
      a = append(a[:1], a...)
      a[0] = 10
      fmt.Println(a)
   }
}
```

Or as another option, you can use linked list:

```
package main

import (
   "container/list"
   "fmt"
)

func main() {
   a := list.New()
   a.PushBack(20)
   a.PushBack(30)
   a.PushFront(10)
   for n := a.Front(); n != nil; n = n.Next() {
      fmt.Println(n.Value)
   }
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/container/list

Comment: `a = append([]int{10}, a...)` is simpler than the append options shown here.

Answer (score -1):

I know the Question is only for `int` but thought I'd add this to the discussion:

https://play.golang.com/p/PNax2a1rL3q

```golang
import (
    "golang.org/x/exp/constraints"
)

type Number interface {
    constraints.Signed | constraints.Unsigned | constraints.Float
}

func prepend[T Number](list []T, elems ...T) []T {
    results := make([]T, len(list)+len(elems))
    results = append(results, 0)
    copy(results[len(elems):], list)
    copy(results[:len(elems)], elems)
    return results
}
```

References:

- [How to write a generic function that accepts any numerical type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67678331/how-to-write-a-generic-function-that-accepts-any-numerical-type)
- https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/constraints

Comment: I downvoted because this seems overly complicated compared to `append(elems, list...)`. It’s also a lot slower (~2.5x to 3x slower on large slices), and the `append(results, 0)` in the middle adds a superfluous `0` in the result.