# How can I write a generic function that accepts any numerical type?

Tags: go, generics

Coming from JavaScript and TypeScript, I wanted to check out Go and make a simple calculator. Since there's the difference between int and float, what is the preferred way to write a function that takes any number?

For example:

```
package main

func add(a float64, b float64) float64 {
  return a + b;
}

func main() {
  a := 1;
  b := 2;
  fmt.Println(add(1, 2)); // 3
  fmt.Println(add(a, b)); // Cannot use a (type int) as type float64 in argument to add
  fmt.Println(add(1.5, 3.2)); // 4.7
  fmt.Println(add(2.5, 2)); // 4.5
}
```

Do I need to convert everything to float (since it "covers" the int range) or do I create a separate functions for each type, like `addInt(a int, b int) int` and `addFloat(a float64, b float64) float64`? Or might there be a more elegant way at all?

Comment: Note that float does not cover the integer range. For large integers, there may be no floating point value that is precisely equal. The general answer, though, is to go back to your actual goal and do that. A simple calculator doesn't work on "any kind of number value." It works on some number type that you design the system around (generally floating point or fixed point). Write your functions for that and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

##### Go 1.18 and above

With the introduction of type parameters in Go 1.18, this is easier to accomplish.

You can define a function parametrized in `T` and use an interface [constraint](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_constraints) to restrict `T` to numeric types.

```
func add[T Number](a, b T) T {
    return a + b
}
```

The constraint `Number` can be defined using [`golang.org/x/exp/constraints` package](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/constraints) (still experimental):

```
import "golang.org/x/exp/constraints"

type Number interface {
    constraints.Integer | constraints.Float
}
```

Where:

- `Number` is the union of the type sets of `constraints.Integer` and `constraints.Float`
- `constraints.Integer` is the set of all signed and unsigned integer types
- `contraints.Float` is the set of float types

This will allow you to call `add` with any two arguments of numeric type. Then in the function body you will be able to use **any operation that is supported by *all* types in the constraint**. So in case of numbers, this includes also arithmetic operators. Then declaring similar functions is easy:

```
func multiply[T Number](a, b T) T {
    return a * b
}
```

Keep in mind that the arguments **must have the same type**. Regardless of generics, you can't use different types; from the specs [Operators](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Operators):

> [...] the operand types must be identical unless the operation involves shifts or untyped constants.

Therefore our generic `add` and `multiply` functions are defined with only one type parameter `T`. This implies that you also can't call the `add` function with untyped constants whose default types are incompatible:

```
add(2.5, 2) // won't compile
```

In this case the compiler will infer the type of `T` from the first argument `2.5`, which defaults to `float64`, and then won't be able to match the type of `2`, which defaults to `int`.

Full program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/exp/constraints"
)

type Number interface {
    constraints.Integer | constraints.Float
}

func main() {
    a := 1
    b := 2
    
    fmt.Println(add(1, 2))     // 3
    fmt.Println(add(a, b))     // 3
    fmt.Println(add(1.5, 3.2)) // 4.7
    // fmt.Println(add(2.5, 2)) // default type int of 2 does not match inferred type float64 for T
}

func add[T Number](a, b T) T {
    return a + b
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/rdqi3_-EdHp

**Warning:** since these functions handle also floats, keep in mind that floats can hold `NaN` values and infinities.

---

**About complex numbers**

Go has `complex64` and `complex128` predeclared types. You can use them too in the `Number` constraint:

```
import "golang.org/x/exp/constraints"

type Number interface {
    constraints.Integer | constraints.Float | constraints.Complex
}
```

This doesn't restrict the capabilities of these generic functions: the arithmetic operators that are supported by integers and floats (only `+`, `-`, `*` and `/`) and all order operators are supported by complex types too. The remainder operator `%` and bitwise operators are supported only by integers, and therefore by type parameters constrained to `constraints.Integer`.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is an experimental feature and it could be removed from the language.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible now thanks to generics, but it's extremely tedious because you have to specify every numeric type by hand in the function declaration.

```
// Adds two integers and returns the result together with a boolean
// which indicates whether an overflow has occurred
func AddInt[I int | uint | int8 | uint8 | int16 | uint16 | int32 | uint32 | int64 | uint64](a, b I) (I, bool) {
    c := a + b
    if (c > a) == (b > 0) {
        return c, true
    }
    return c, false
}
```

You could also define an interface that will contain the verbose list of int types

```
type Int interface {
    int | uint | int8 | uint8 | int16 | uint16 | int32 | uint32 | int64 | uint64
}

// Adds two integers and returns the result together with a boolean
// which indicates whether an overflow has occurred
func AddInt[I Int](a, b I) (I, bool) {
    c := a + b
    if (c > a) == (b > 0) {
            return c, true
    }
    return c, false
}
```

There is a [constraints](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/constraints) package that provides a more DRY way of defining such functions, but it's experimental and could be removed from the language at some point, so I wouldn't recommend using it.

Comment: As ugly as it might look like, this option does allow you to cast into the chosen type using `I(1234)`, something that the above answers using `constraints` do not allow.

Answer (score 3):

**Up until Go 1.17 (pre-generics).** See other answer(s) for an updated solution

---

The simplest option is to just convert arguments at the call site.

```golang
add(float64(a), float64(b))
```

Comment: I think this answers the question for now, although it can lead to imprecision. And it might be simpler to just define all value which potentially will be added in the future as float64 to prevent the conversion on each run. Also I'm a bit sad there are no generics (yet it seems?) but I can also understand the cost that comes with adding the feature

Comment: The "everything is a float" method is how JavaScript itself works by the way https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Number . Generics are planned (and loosely scheduled) for addition to the language. It has been demanded since forever, but the project has been inherently resistant to big changes and generics will be by far the biggest change since Go 1.